# Sort date in Descending

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

I am using the below code to display a control which shows a date along with a hyperlink.

```
<li>
  <div><%# FormatDateTime(Eval("Date"), "dd MMM yyyy") %></div>
  <div>
    <a href='/portal<%# Eval("Path") %>.aspx' target='_blank'>
     <%# Eval("Name") %>
    </a>
  </div>
</li>
```

How can I display the list of items in orderby descending for date?

Comment: How're you retrieving the data you're displaying? If you're using SQL, you can use an `ORDER BY [ColumnName] DESC` clause. If it's a `List<>` of objects with a date property, you could use the Linq `OrderByDescending()` method. There are lots of alternatives depending on what you're doing.

Comment: @Diado - I use kentico tool where we configure the data source.

Comment: My point was that you haven't included any code that involves anything that can be ordered - no list, model, loop etc. Is there a level above the `<li>` that you can add to your question, or an example of how you're getting the data perhaps?

Comment: @Diado - is it possible to sort the list using JavaScript/jquery?